# How to retain checkbox in white color and text in base control color?

Tags: c#, .net, checkbox, paint

I am using base control library of an application in my form. So using this library all the controls on my form get properties of base control, which make their color as gray just like base control. What I need to do if I want to make only the rectangle of check box in white color and the text as the base control. I tried check_box_Paint event but it is not working for me. Please advise.

Comment: can you start off by providing / showing what code you have in the event handler in question.?

Comment: if an option : Make another base class that derived from your control (and use this) and use overloading.